# Separate Million and Billion Data from one column

Tags: r

I am trying below code for separating "M" and "B" with their values in 2 different column.

I want output like this:

```
level 1    level 2
M 3.2      B 3.6
M 4        B 2.8
           B 3.5
```

Input:

```
reve=c("M 3.2","B 3.6","B 2.8","B 3.5","M 4")
#class(reve)
data=data.frame(reve)
```

Here is what I have tried.

```
index=which(grepl("M ",data$reve)
data$reve=gsub("M ","",data$reve)
data$reve=gsub("B ","",data$reve)

data$reve=as.numeric(data$reve)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a data frame you can do that with dplyr   *separate()*

I give you an example of this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(coupe = c("M 2.3", "M 4.5", "B 1"))
df %>% separate(coupe, c("MorB","Quant"), " ")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
#  MorB  Quant
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 M     2.3  
#2 M     4.5  
#3 B     1
```

Hope it help you!

For counting the number of "M" rows:

```
 df %>% separate(YourColumn, c("MorB","Quant"), " ") %>% 
 filter(MorB == "M") %>% nrow()
```

Comment: I had tried this code but separate code gives error. I want answer of this:   
Count how many observations in this column are recorded in Millions of dollars. company advertising $1.2B  $34B $5.6M $7B  $4.2M$9.7M                        
company advertising is column in a data frame and I want to count number of rows in millions of dollars.

Comment: df %>% separate(YourColumn, c("MorB","Quant"), " ") %>% filter(MorB == "M") %>% nrow()        You are welcome

Comment: When I run this above code I got error : error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "separate"

Comment: df<-data.frame(data$company_advertisement)                                               df %>% separate(company_advertisement, c("MorB","Quant"), " ") %>% filter(MorB == "M") %>% nrow()                                                                  
 after this I got error: error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "Seperat"

Comment: Man write library(dplyr)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `base R` approach.

```
lst <- split(reve, substr(reve, 1, 1))
df1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
df1
#      B     M
#1 B 3.6 M 3.2
#2 B 2.8   M 4
#3 B 3.5  <NA>
```

`split` the vector in two by the first letter. This gives you a list with  entries of unequal length. Use `lapply` to make the entries having the same length, i.e. append the shorter one with `NA`s. Call `as.data.frame`.

If you want to change the names, you can use `setNames`

```
setNames(df1, c("level_2", "level_1"))
```

---

In case I misunderstood your desired output, try

```
df1 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, (strsplit(reve, " "))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1[] <- lapply(df1, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
df1
#  X1  X2
#1  M 3.2
#2  B 3.6
#3  B 2.8
#4  B 3.5
#5  M 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can count **Millions** or **Billions** as follows:

**Input datatset:**

```
reve=c("M 3.2","B 3.6","B 2.8","B 3.5","M 4")
data=data.frame(reve)
```

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  separate(reve, c("Label", "Value"),extra = "merge") %>%
  group_by(Label) %>% 
  summarise(n = n())
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
 Label     n
  <chr> <int>
 1 B         3
 2 M         2
```

Comment: Count how many observations in this column are recorded in Millions of dollars. company advertising $1.2B  $34B $5.6M $7B  $4.2M$9.7M                        
company advertising is column in a data frame and I want to count number of rows in millions of dollars.

Comment: @Kalyani: Can you please expected output in the question? It looks unclear to me.

Comment: I want number of rows which having millions of dollar. suppose Company_advertising $1.2B   $34B   $5.6M   $7B   $9.7M $9.1M  then I want rows which having Millions of Dollar. In this case it is $5.6M    $9.7M  $9.1M   and count is =3.

Comment: @Kalyani: I have updated answer. Please check and let me know in case of question.

Answer (score 0):

I think options rooted in regex may also be helpful for these types of problems

```
 reve=c("M 3.2","B 3.6","B 2.8","B 3.5","M 4")

 data=data.frame(reve, stringsAsFactors = F) # handle your data as strings, not factors

 # regex to extract M vals and B vals
 mvals <- stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(data, "M+\\s[0-9]\\.[0-9]|M+\\s[0-9]")[[1]]
 bvals <- stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(data, "B+\\s[0-9]\\.[0-9]|B+\\s[0-9]")[[1]]

 # gluing things together into a single df
 len <- max(length(mvals), length(bvals)) # find the length
 data.frame(M = c(mvals, rep(NA, len - length(mvals))) # ensure vectors are the same size
           ,B = c(bvals, rep(NA, len - length(bvals)))) # ensure vectors are the same size
```

In case regex is unfamiliar, the first expression searches for "M" followed by a space, then by digits 0 through 9, then a period, then digits 0 through 9 again.  The vertical pipe is on "or" operator, so the expression also searches for "M" followed by a space, then digits 0 through 9.  The second half of the expression accounts for cases like "M 4".  The second expression does the same thing, just for lines that contain "B" in lieu of "M".

These are quick and dirty regex statements.  I'm sure cleaner formulations are possible to get the same results.